# For loop inside of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

The code below works, but I need to run a loop for the results. For example where it says $results0 I need it to say $results[$var].

```
for($i = 0; $i < (count($results0)); $i++) {
    $teams[$i] = array(
        $results0[$i],
        $results1[$i],
        $results2[$i],
        $results3[$i],
        $results4[$i],
    );
}

$teams1 = array_sort($teams, $sortVar, SORT_ASC);
```

I realize you cannot do this but I need something that looks like this but actually works:

```
for($i = 0; $i < (count($results0)); $i++) {
    $teams[$i] = array(
        for($j = 0; $j < (count($teams)); $j++) {
            ${'results'.$j}[$i],
    );
        }
}

$teams1 = array_sort($teams, $sortVar, SORT_ASC);
```

Also now I need to be able to sort by category. Thanks in advance, I'm aware my current code may not be secure, I'm doing that after I'm finished.

Comment: The first thing I would do is as zerkms described, wrapping your results1, results2, results3 in an array. But, if you can't do that, you can try `$_GLOBALS['results' . $j]`.

Comment: Won't let me put a loop inside the array like I need to. Tried using $_globals
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOR, expecting ')' in

Comment: @zrmoffett: "Won't let me put a loop inside the array like I need to." --- it makes no sense. "I need to" - is not a technical requirement and likely an XY-problem. The most important for you to realize now is that "you are doing it wrong". Just that. When you are ready to understand that and are willing to start writing better code - come back with another question.

Comment: @zrmoffett: I am helping a lot of people here. Your question: 1. is unclear 2. doesn't make sense. But you don't want to improve it. Instead of trying to explain the original task - you're arguing about your question quality. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - this is what your question is about atm.

Comment: `$results0[0] = 1;$i=0;$j=0;
    echo ${'results'.$j}[$i];` works fine (it spit out a "1").

Answer (score 2):

You might simply use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$results1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$results2 = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$results3 = array('I', 'II', 'III');

$zipped = array_map(function($r1, $r2, $r3) {
    return array($r1, $r2, $r3);
}, $results1, $results2, $results3);

var_dump($zipped);
```

We unlikely are able to provide an answer to the question about sorting since we have no idea what is "category" in your code. It doesn't appear anywhere. But give [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) a try.

Comment: I cannot use $result1, $result2, $result 3 since I will not know how many $results will be. It could be just $result0 or up to $result6

Comment: @zrmoffett: why don't you use array instead? `$result[0]`, `$result[1]`... ?

Comment: Read what I asked, and you will see.

Comment: @zrmoffett: I have read it already. And I don't see any reason why to avoid using arrays in favour of weird `$resultsN`. But anyway, if you don't want to help us to help - then good luck in solving what you're in stuck with! Have a nice day!

Comment: $resultN is a different array. Using multiple dimensions.

Comment: @zrmoffett: so? Why not have all of them in a **single array**? What is the *technical reason* to have multiple variables?

Comment: It's obvious if you read my original post, move on you can't help me.